# & operator in predicate (filter) - How to base the filter on multiple column values?

Tags: rust-polars

I am trying to filter a Polars dataframe based on two columns values. In the the [rust user guide](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/notebooks/introduction_polars-rs.html) I could only find a predicate based filter based on one column value.

**How do I add additional columns in the predicate and return a boolean?**

I am trying to keep rows where job="Social worker" AND "sex"="M" (may be additional columns if need be)

```
    use polars::{prelude::*, lazy::dsl::col};
    // use the predicate to filter
    let predicate = (col("job").eq(lit("Social worker")) & (col("sex").eq(lit("M")))); 
   
    let filtered_df = df
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .filter(predicate )
        .collect()
        .unwrap();
```

The error I get that it says the & operator cannot be used here and it does not check the two conditions.

[The error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl1Rj.png)

```
error[E0369]: no implementation for \Expr & Expr``
|
23 | let predicate = col("job").eq(lit("Social worker")) & col("sex").eq(lit("M"));
| ----------------------------------- ^ ----------------------- Expr
| |
| Expr
```

If I only use one condition the filter works as required. The following code returns the correct output.

```
// use the predicate to filter
    let predicate = col("job").eq(lit("Social worker"));
   
    let filtered_df = df
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .filter(predicate )
        .collect()
        .unwrap();
```

Thank you for your help and reply.

I have tried using the `&` operator `.and()` and `assert!` none of those worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A user named Patryk27 on reddit gave me some heads up [(docs)](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.and) and asked me to try the `expr.and(bar)` syntax and it **Worked**!

If your filter is based on multiple column values you can use the predicate in the following way. I wish this was part of the documentation in Polars as well.

```
// use the predicate to filter
let predicate = col("job").eq(lit("Social worker")).and(col("sex").eq(lit("F"))).and(col("name").eq(lit("Elizabeth Walsh")));
       
let filtered_df = df
                  .clone()
                  .lazy()
                  .filter(predicate)
                  .collect()
                  .unwrap();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can chain filters.

```
let pred_1 = col("job").eq(lit("Social worker"); 
let pred_2 = col("sex").eq(lit("M");


let filtered_df = df.filter(pred_1)
                    .filter(pred_2)
```